# Is there a built-in function in PHP/Laravel that parses "a=1,b=2,c=3" to array ['a'=>'1', 'b'=>'2', 'c'=>'3']?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a string with key=value pairs separated by commas. I'm looking for a function in PHP/Laravel that can convert that string as an array with the given keys and values.

Given:

> "a=1,b=2,c=3"

Expected return:

> ['a'=>'1', 'b'=>'2', 'c'=>'3']

What I have so far is a function of 8 lines and am worried that I'm reinventing the wheel.

```
public static function breakValues($string) {
    return collect(str_getcsv($string))->mapWithKeys(
        function ($item) {
            $valuePair = explode( '=', $item);
            return [$valuePair[0] => $valuePair[1]];
        }
    );
}
```

- Extra thought: Would be nice if it can detect invalid value pairs(no equal separator)

Any function comes to mind?

Comment: [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) & [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str)

Comment: @mario, fair enough, basically you convert the string to &-delimited and do strtr. String pre-manipulation sounds additional process but I believe this is better than mine exploding "=". You may post this as answer ;) parse_str( strtr("a=1,b=2,c=3", ',', '&'), $res);